# Isomorphism between non Banach space and Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I know that a non complete normed space cannot be topologically isomorphic to a complete normed space. However there exist bijective and bounded linear mapping from a Banach space onto a non Banach space.

For example, identity mapping from C([a , b]) with sup norm onto itself with L2 norm. Because the topology on the former is strictly finer than the topology on later.

But I am finding it difficult to find a bijective and bounded linear mapping from a non Banach space onto a Banach space. Is there any such example and if not then how to prove it. May be I am missing some simple result. Any help please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impossible as a consequence of the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis))

Comment: How open mapping theorem leads to this conclusion. Can you please give some hint.

Comment: Never mind, I was mistaken

Answer (score 1):

The following Example is taken from Bühler and Salamon's book "Functional Analysis". You can find it on page 57, Example 2.2.8. It is preceeded by two other examples that show that in the open mapping theorem and the inverse operator theorem for Banach spaces, the assumption that the source and the target are complete, cannot be removed.

[image]

Comment: Another example is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3951059/does-a-bounded-from-below-linear-operator-with-target-set-equal-to-the-domain-al/3951303#3951303

Comment: Thank you so much.